# How to make geth log RPC calls?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I want to see the logs of the JSON-RPC calls to geth (with all the details if possible). How can I do that? In this [page](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options), I have found a command line option:

> --vmodule value           Per-module verbosity: comma-separated list of = (e.g. eth/*=6,p2p=5)

However I don't know how it should like to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 2):

In `geth console`:

```js
// from `geth --help`:
//   --verbosity value         Logging verbosity: 0=silent, 1=error, 2=warn, 3=info, 4=debug, 5=detail (default: 3)
//   --vmodule value           Per-module verbosity: comma-separated list of <pattern>=<level> (e.g. eth/*=5,p2p=4)
> debug.vmodule('rpc=5')
```

Same should work from command-line:

`geth --vmodule 'rpc=5'`

This doesn't seem to be logging request contents, though.